# Access value of a hidden div from inside an angular app in an iframe

Tags: html, angular, iframe, elementref

I need to get a value of strings in a hidden div from inside an angular app. Here is what I have:

```
<iframe id="sample">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div id="testString" display="none;">string </div>
            <app></app>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

How can I access the value of div `testString` inside the Angular app in non root component? 
tried with these and get null:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('testString').textContent
document.getElementById('testString').textContent
```

Can it be done with ElementRef?
Also how can I secure this string against injection and xss attacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular is just Javascript (well, typescript which is also just Javascript with types). So you can do the exact same thing in Angular as you would in raw Javascript, just put it under a `ngOnInit` method in the component so that `document` has loaded. If you've used jQuery, this is basically the equivilant of `$(document).ready()`.

For the record, I'm not saying that there wouldn't be a more "Angular" way to accomplish what you're asking. `ElementRef` would also work, as it's basically just a wrapper around `document.getElement*`. My point is that you don't **need** to write anything special just because you're using Angular.